# "any" constrained as keyof not working Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here are the definitions I currently have:

```
interface Action<T extends string, P> {
  type: T;
  payload: P;
}

type ActionDefinitions = {
  setNumber: number;
  setString: string;
}

type ActionCreator<A extends keyof ActionDefinitions> =
  () => Action<A, ActionDefinitions[A]>;
```

My thinking is that when I make an `ActionCreator<any>`, `any` must be constrained to a key of `ActionDefinitions`. This is important because when I define a type like this:

```
type Creators = {
  [K: string]: ActionCreator<keyof ActionDefinitions>
};
```

I need automatic type inference for each value in this object. So for example, if I were to define a `Creators` object like this:

```
const testCreators: Creators = {
  foo: () => ({
    type: "setNumber",
    payload: "string",
  })
}
```

This should cause an error because `foo` should be inferred to be an `ActionCreator<"setNumber">`, which should be of type `Action<"setNumber", number>`, and therefore the `payload` should be a number, not a string.

However, TypeScript simply allows `payload` to be of any type, which seems wrong because if the generic type `A` is equal to "setNumber", then `foo` should have to return `Action<"setNumber", ActionDefinitions["setNumber"]>`, i.e., `Action<"setNumber", number>`...but it allows `any` instead of `number`.

Anyone know why this is or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `keyof ActionDefinitions` is a *union* type and passing it into `ActionCreator` you eventually get type:

```ts
type ActionCreator = () => Action<keyof ActionDefinitions, string | number>
```

That allows `string | number` as a payload.

What you really need is to *iterate* over keys of `keyof ActionDefinitions` and pass concrete keys into `ActionCreator`:

```ts
type Creators = {
  [K: string]: { [I in keyof ActionDefinitions]: ActionCreator<I> }[keyof ActionDefinitions]
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3AQ3w)

---

updated with a bit more generic version of `ActionCreator` type:

```ts
type ActionCreator<T, K extends Extract<keyof T, string> = Extract<keyof T, string>> = {
  [I in K]: () => Action<I, T[I]>;
}[K]

type Creators = {
  [K: string]: ActionCreator<ActionDefinitions>
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOaelm)